# Comparison of cat pipe awk operation to awk command on a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

While trying to optimize few of my server related data, I and my team had a discussion over the usage of linux commands. Would request the members to please help us understand the concept more precisely.

On servers we have log files which are created every minutes and we need to search logs with specific tags for example: Error logs, Timeout Logs, Request fail logs. Out of many, one requirement is to provide information about the count of these tags

The simple logic would be to awk the specific field(with delimiter) to sort and uniq -c command to count the number of such instances.

I can see two ways to perform it:

```
cat fname | awk -F":" {'print $1'} | sort | uniq -c
```

and

```
awk -F":" {'print $1'} fname | sort | uniq -c
```

The file size can go in GB's so which command could be more effective.

Comment: Why not `grep "TAG" log.txt | wc -l`

Comment: Awk is great for field manipulation, but for simple counting, I would use grep.

Comment: the problem with grep is it will count the tags if available in other fields as well. For example: A "timeout tag" will have a description as "Error while trying to connect IP". So we might get wrong counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 ways to open a file and have awk operate on it's contents:

1. cat opens the file:

   ```
   cat file | awk '...'
   ```
2. shell redirection opens the file:

   ```
   awk '...' < file
   ```
3. awk opens the file

   ```
   awk '...' file
   ```

Of those choices:

1. is always to be avoided as the `cat` and pipe are using resources and providing no value, google UUOC (Useless Use Of Cat) for details.

Which of the other 2 to use is debatable:

2. has the advantage that the shell is opening the file rather than the tool so you can rely on consistent error handling if you do this for all tools
3. has the advantage that the tool knows the name of the file it is operating on (e.g. FILENAME in awk) so you can use that internally.

To see the difference, consider these 2 files:

```
$ ls -l file1 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 Ed None 4 Mar 30 09:55 file1
--w------- 1 Ed None 0 Mar 30 09:55 file2
$ cat file1
a
b
$ cat file2
cat: file2: Permission denied
```

and see what happens when you try to run awk on the contents of both using both methods of opening them:

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' < file1
- a
- b

$ awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' file1
file1 a
file1 b

$ awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' < file2
-bash: file2: Permission denied

$ awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' file2
awk: fatal: cannot open file `file2' for reading (Permission denied)
```

Note that the error message for opening the unreadable file, file2, when you use redirection came from the shell and so looked exactly like the error message when I first tried to `cat` it while the error message when letting awk open it came from awk and is different from the shell message and would be different across various awks.

Note that when using awk to open the file, FILENAME was populated with the name of the file being operated on but when using redirection to open the file it was set to `-`.

I personally think that the benefit of "3" (populated FILENAME) vastly outweighs the benefit of "2" (consistent error handling of file open errors) and so I would always use:

```
awk '...' file
```

and for your particular problem you'd use:

```
awk -F':' '{cnt[$1]++} END{for (i in cnt) print cnt[i], i}' fname
```

Answer (score 5):

Definitely useless `cat` should be avoided by using:

```
awk -F":" '{print $1}' fname | sort | uniq -c
```

But my recommendation is to even avoid expensive `sort` and `uniq` command by finding unique items in `awk` itself by using:

```
awk -F":" '!seen[$1]++' fname
```

This will print unique lines.

To get unique counts:

```
awk -F":" '!count[$1]++{c++} END{print c}' fname
```

Comment: A simpler alternative would be `awk -F":" '!seen[$1]++' fname`

Comment: when you use an array named `seen` the intent is to do something differently with just the first instance vs all other instances of the key so you should change the name to `count` or similar. Also, as written your 2nd script will just print every unique key twice.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, yes I had extra `END` block, it is edited now.

Answer (score 1):

`cat fname |` slows things down a little as it has to copy the file from the disk to the kernel then to cat's buffer, then to a pipe, which goes to the kernel again, and then to another process. It's not by a lot, as it should only be a linear slow-down and in-memory copying is quite fast, but you can **always** (=without depending on `some_command`s accepting file arguments) speed things up by replacing

```
cat one_file_name | some_command
```

with

```
<one_file_name some_command
```

which will be faster, as it will directly set one_file_name as `stdin` of `some_command`.

`<one_file_name` can be and often is placed *after* `some_command` and before the next pipe symbol. I personally often like to start with it as it mirrors the left-to-right flow of the useless, but somewhat common use of cat (`cat one_file_name`).

Comment: Your point about using redirection rather than `cat` is valid but it ignores the fact that many tools accept a file name as an argument, so no redirection is necessary.