# Performance considerations when using pipe | within awk

Tags: unix, awk

```
awk -F'/' '{ print $1 |" sort " }' infile > outfile
```

versus

```
awk -F'/' '{ print $1 }' infile | sort > outfile
```

Are these MVCE's exactly equivalent or are there portability / performance issues that I don't know about if I use a pipe ( or a redirect ) from within `awk`.

Both commands produce the correct output.

Update: Did some research myself - see my answer below.

Comment: Sorry my answer was wrong. Both commands are doing more or less the same - as long as you run in a shell that supports the pipe operator.

Comment: @hek2mgl Good point about windows. The "more or less"  is exactly that I'm wondering about.

Comment: Sorry for my vague wording. Right is: The commands doing the same. However, as long as it is sure that it will run in a shell that supports the pipe I would recommend the shell pipe solution.

Comment: For this simple example I agree, its much clearer. But the idea might come in handy if you were piping different parts of your output to various places in a more complex scenario.

Comment: Sure, but then the question is not applicable any more since that would be simply not possible with the shell.

Comment: `awk '{ print $2 | " sort " }
       { print $1 | " sort -f " }'  infile`  for example

Comment: Yeah, don't get me wrong it would be possible with awk, but not with the shell. That's why the comparison makes not much sense any more.. Isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr Using a pipe within awk can be *twice* as slow.

I went and had a quick read through of io.c in the gawk source.

Piping with awk *is* POSIX as long as you don't use co-processes. ie `|&`

If you have an OS that doesn't support pipes (this came up in the comments), gawk will simulate them by writing to files like you'd expect. That will take a while but at least you *have* pipes when you didn't.

If you have a real OS, it will fork children and write the output there, so you wouldn't expect a huge performance drop by using the pipe within awk.

Interestingly though gawk has some optimisations for simple cases like

```
awk '{print $1}'
```

so I ran a test case.

```
for i in $(seq 1 10000000); do echo $(( 10000000-$i )) " " $i;done > infile
```

Ten million records seemed like enough to smooth out variance from other jobs on the system.

Then

```
time awk '{ print $1 }' infile | sort -n > /dev/null

real    0m10.350s
user    0m7.770s
sys     0m3.000s
```

or thereabouts on average.

*but*

```
time awk '{ print $1 | " sort -n " }' infile > /dev/null

real    0m25.870s
user    0m13.880s
sys     0m13.030s
```

As you can see this is quite a dramatic difference.

So the conclusion:
 Although it can be potentially much slower there are plenty of use cases where the gains far outweigh the extra performance hit. It really is only in simple cases like the MVCE where you should keep the pipe outside.

There is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340587/comparision-of-cat-pipe-awk-operation-to-awk-command-on-a-file) about the difference between redirecting into `awk` versus calling `awk` with a filename. Although not directly related, it might be of interest if you have bothered to read this far.

Comment: I think it is not so black and white. There are use cases of having an internal pipe in `awk` that make what you are writing easier to express. Perhaps the conclusion is 'for the simple case of `awk 'something' | sort` use that. For the more complicated cases, an internal `awk` pipe is a handy resource with the cost of slower execution...'

Comment: @dawg Edited my conclusion, like you suggested. Hope its clearer now. That was really what I was trying to say all along.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `|` inside `awk`, the output of the print statements accumulate into a single string and then the shell command inside of "xxx" is executed with that string.

Consider:

```
$ echo 1 4 2 3 | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'
1
4
2
3
```

Now try:

```
$ echo 1 4 2 3 | awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i | "sort" }' 
1
2
3
4
```

The single string of `1\n4\n2\n3` is being constructed internally and then passed by awk to `sort` This could be combined into a more complex invocation, such as:

```
awk '{ print $1 > "names.unsorted"
   command = "sort -r > names.sorted"
   print $1 | command }' names
```

More at GNU awk manual on [redirection.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Redirection.html)

Comment: It still isn't clear to me whether there is a performance overhead involved in this accumulation, and whether it is portable outside of GNU implementations - those are the questions I'm asking.

Comment: The use of `|` is POSIX; The use of `|&` (to have coprocess) is gawk specific. I cannot say whether one is 'better' or not. I would use the one that works the best!

Comment: I went and grabbed the awk source code - will post an answer if I can figure it out one way or the other. Can't leave it alone now that I've posed the question. -- possible character flaw on my part ;)