# How to extract string from a file in bash

Tags: awk

I have a file called DB_create.sql which has this line

```
CREATE DATABASE testrepo;
```

I want to extract only testrepo from this. So I've tried

> cat DB_create.sql | awk '{print $3}'

This gives me **testrepo;**

I need only testrepo. How do I get this ?

Comment: I don’t think AWK is the most suitable tool here. I’d use sed: `sed -n '/^CREATE DATABASE \(.*\);$/s//\1/p' DB_create.sql`. But even that’s brittle because it doesn’t understand SQL, it just looks for verbatim character-by-character match. This can be fine in a pinch but a robust solution *requires* an SQL parser.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
awk -F'[ ;]' '{print $(NF-1)}' DB_create.sql
```

***OR***

```
awk -F'[ ;]' '{print $3}' DB_create.sql
```

OR without setting any field separators try:

```
awk '{sub(/;$/,"");print $3}'  DB_create.sql
```

Simple explanation would be: making field separator as space OR semi colon and then printing 2nd last field`($NF-1)` which is required by OP here. Also you need not to use `cat` command with `awk` because `awk` can read Input_file by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Using `gnu awk`, you can set record separator as `;` + line break:

```sh
awk -v RS=';\r?\n' '{print $3}' file.sql

testrepo
```

Or using any POSIX awk, just do a call to `sub` to strip trailing `;`:

```sh
awk '{sub(/;$/, "", $3); print $3}' file.sql

testrepo
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
awk -F'[;[:space:]]+' '{print $3}' DB_create.sql
```

where the field separator is set to a `[;[:space:]]+` regex that matches one or more occurrences of `;` or/and whitespace chars. Then, Field 3 will contain the string you need without the semi-colon.

More pattern details:

- `[` - start of a bracket expression

  - `;`  - a `;` char
  - `[:space:]` - any whitespace char
- `]` - end of the bracket expression
- `+` - a POSIX ERE *one or more occurrences* quantifier.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/KaYND2).

Answer (score 1):

Use your own code but adding the function `sub()`:

```
cat DB_create.sql | awk '{sub(/;$/, "",$3);print $3}'
```

Although it's better not using `cat`. Here you can see why: [Comparison of cat pipe awk operation to awk command on a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29340587/comparison-of-cat-pipe-awk-operation-to-awk-command-on-a-file)

So better this way:

```
awk '{sub(/;$/, "",$3);print $3}' file
```